# PhantomJS version 1.4.0 version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs

I installed PhantomJS today and got this error trying to use it:

```
PhantomJS version 1.4.0
is too old. You must use at least version 1.7.0  
(Capybara::Poltergeist::PhantomJSTooOld)
```

How can I install the newer version?

I can *get* the newer version (1.7) at: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Once I've downloaded it though how do I actually install it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Linux or OS X? You'll need to either build from source or install an updated PhantomJS package. You can also download the binaries and install over the system installed PhantomJS. Type "which phantomjs" and it should show the location of PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using homebrew, just:

```
brew upgrade phantomjs
```

Comment: It's actually `brew upgrade phantomjs`

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem yesterday, it required me updating brew, telling brew to uninstall phantomJS, then updating xcode, then installing the latest xcode command utilities, then using brew to re-install phantomjs.  Finally that got it to pull in the latest version.  You might try this (mac):

1. brew update
2. brew uninstall phantomjs
3. brew doctor (follow the fixes it recommends if any... Mine was updating xcode)
4. brew install phantomjs

At that point it should grab the latest.

Good luck!